# In SSRS, trying to use Last(), to return last row from dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have an expression outside my table, where i'm trying to read the last record in from my dataset.  Is Last() not a valid function or something?  It's not erroring, just nothing is getting displayed.

=Last(Fields!IntialBalanceRolling.Value, "SupplierTransaction")

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your data descending and use this:

```
=First(Fields!IntialBalanceRolling.Value, "SupplierTransaction")
```

Comment: I have a table which is stores transaction data so i need it to come in ASC to populate my table.  I could write another stored proc to just get the starting balance, but i was hoping i didn't have to since I already have the value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you last row has a null value for this column?